# how to create a new item related to a function against previous data in C# linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<History> data = new List<History>()
    {
        new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.0m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1) },
        new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.1m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 2) },
        new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.4m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 3) },
        new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.7m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 4) },
        new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.8m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 5) },
        new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.0m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 7) },
        new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.1m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 8) },
        new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.4m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 9) },
        new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.7m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 10) },
        new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.8m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 11) },

        new History() {Symbol="b", Close = 1.6m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1) },
        new History() {Symbol="b", Close = 1.2m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 2) },
        new History() {Symbol="b", Close = 1.4m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 3) },
        new History() {Symbol="b", Close = 1.8m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 4) },
        new History() {Symbol="b", Close = 1.2m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 5) },
        new History() {Symbol="b", Close = 2.0m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 7) },
        new History() {Symbol="b", Close = 1.4m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 8) },
        new History() {Symbol="b", Close = 1.4m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 9) },
        new History() {Symbol="b", Close = 1.0m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 10) },
        new History() {Symbol="b", Close = 2.8m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 11) },

        new History() {Symbol="c", Close = 2.0m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1) },
        new History() {Symbol="c", Close = 2.1m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 2) },
        new History() {Symbol="c", Close = 1.4m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 3) },
        new History() {Symbol="c", Close = 2.7m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 4) },
        new History() {Symbol="c", Close = 1.2m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 5) },
        new History() {Symbol="c", Close = 1.3m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 7) },
        new History() {Symbol="c", Close = 2.2m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 8) },
        new History() {Symbol="c", Close = 1.3m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 9) },
        new History() {Symbol="c", Close = 2.6m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 10) },
        new History() {Symbol="c", Close = 1.9m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 11) },
    };

var StockGroupList = data
           .GroupBy(o => o.Symbol)
           .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
           .ToList();
```

I want create a new List like

```
select new { Symbol, Close, Date, Vol};
```

Here `Vol` is the five day standard deviation e.g `Vol` of `Symbol="a"` at `2016, 2, 5` is  function of `close` of `2016, 2, 1` to `2016, 2, 5` and The first four days `Vol` (e.g `2016, 2, 1` to `2016, 2, 4`) is default as `Vol = 0`.

Expected output:

```
List<dynamic> NewData = new List<dynamic>
{ 
       new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.0m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1), Vol = 0 },
       new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.1m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 2), Vol = 0 },
       new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.4m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 3), Vol = 0 }, 
       new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.7m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 4), Vol = 0 },
       new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.8m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 5), Vol = SD(XXX) }, 
       new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.0m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 7), Vol = SD(XXX) },
                                ......

};
```

You can regard `SD(xxx)` as a given function, saying the sum of ten days simplely but do not use the method inputing one by one since actually here `ten` may be replaced by a large number in the large data.
Furthermore, if `SD` is following form

```
using MathNet.Numerics.Statistics;
decimal OneStdDev = (decimal)(new DescriptiveStatistics(data.Select(o => (double)o.Close)).StandardDeviation);
```

What sould I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you right but I think you are looking for something like that. (For simplicity I replaced the StdDev function by an `Average` function).

```
int dayspan = 5;
var result = from history in data
    let lastCloses =
            from history1 in data
            where history.Symbol == history1.Symbol 
                && history.Date >= history1.Date 
                && history.Date - history1.Date <= TimeSpan.FromDays(dayspan)
            select history1.Close
    select new {
        Symbol = history.Symbol, 
        Close = history.Close, 
        Date = history.Date, 
        Vol = lastCloses.Count() >= dayspan ? lastCloses.Average() : 0};
```

UPDATE:

If you can't rely on the dates and want to use list positions instead you can't use Linq query syntax but Linq method syntax:

```
int dayspan = 5;

var result = data.Select(
    delegate(History history, int index)
    {
        decimal[] vol = data
                .Select((history1, index1) => new {History = history1, Index = index1})
                .Where(x => x.Index <= index 
                    && index - x.Index < dayspan 
                    && x.History.Symbol == history.Symbol)
                .Select(x => x.History.Close).ToArray();
        return new
        {
            Symbol = history.Symbol,
            Close = history.Close,
            Date = history.Date,
            Vol = vol.Count() == dayspan ? vol.Average() : 0
        };
    });
```

For reasons of readability maybe it is better to use simple loops to solve this problem instead of Linq :-)

Comment: Here date is a trading day instead of natural calendar day, thus`history.Date - history1.Date <= TimeSpan.FromDays(dayspan)` may not be correct, sorry I am fresh in LINQ.